# Grafana annotations work inconsistently

Tags: graphite, grafana

I am using grafana to pull in graphite events and overlay them on graphs as annotations. This seems to work very inconsistently for me so I was hoping that someone might have an idea as to what I may be doing wrong.

I am able to see all of the events in the graphite dashboard so I know they are available.

When I create the annotation I am using Graphite event tags:

[image: Annotation]

The one above seems to work as expected:

[image: Expected result]

I added a second annotation and this one does not seem to show up at all. When I look at the network console in Chrome, both annotations are being fetched as expected but for some reason the second one is not added to the screen:

First network event (appears on graph):

```
[{"data": "Fixed issue with metrics not being collected properly for bamboo.", "what": "metrics bug fixed", "when": 1444197389.0, "id": 11, "tags": "bamboo_events"}]
```

Second network event (does not appear on graph):

```
[{"data": "Sync graphiteprod-c02 data to graphiteprod-c01", "what": "sync", "when": 1446665626.0, "id": 13, "tags": "testtag"}]
```

I have tried creating new a new dashboard that only has the second annotation defined and it does not show up there as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there might be a discrepancy between the graphite event epoch time and grafana.

For graphite it is returning 2015-11-04 08:33:46 as 1446662026.0
When compared to the current epoch time (1446651804) the graphite event is in the future. It seems that the time is showing about 5 hours in the future, might be some sort of issue with time zone conversion.